# Update cached file on chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have never dealt with an issue like this before. I've tried deleting the cache on chrome 4 different ways, but no avail.

I've uploaded updated files to the server and when I view the file in my FTP app it shows the updated javascript file, but when I goto the live site and view the js file I get my old javascript file.

[image: weird]

Comment: imgur images come and go. You need to put the example code here for future value.

Comment: _"I've tried deleting the cache on chrome 4 different ways, but no avail."_ What are the four different ways that you have tried? Did you disable cache after clearing cache?

Comment: @Rob I wanted to show the difference between chrome inspector and what's being showed on my ftp client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the .htaccess file on the site to see if it has any caching set-up.

Try incognito-mode in chrome to work-around caching / cookies.

This extension is handy: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=en